# Promise not getting resolved inside reduce array method javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await

I have large array of objects and filtered the objects based on the userID. Here is the code below.

```
const filteredArr = LargeArr.Items.reduce(
            async(acc, { attributes: { dob, name, picture} = { dob: null, name: null, picture: null }, userID }) => {
                let pic = null;
                if (picture) { pic = await getPic(picture); } // async here
                acc[userID] = { name, userID, pic, dob };
                return acc;
            }, {});
```

Expected Output :

```
{
  '1595232114269': {
    name: 'Mark Status',
    userID: '1595232114269',
    picture: 'mark-status.jpg',
    dob: '2020-08-10'
  },
  '48e69555d778f9b9a3a1d553b9c3b8f7dd6a3394ac82df1433b60a69c055d23d': {
    name: 'Jack Thomas',
    userID: '48e69555d778f9b9a3a1d553b9c3b8f7dd6a3394ac82df1433b60a69c055d23d',
    picture: 'jack-thomas.jpg',
    dob: '1990-12-20'
  },
  '48e69555d778f9b9a3a1d553b9c3b8f7dd6a3394ac82df1433b60a69c055d47p': {
    name: 'Petro Huge',
    userID: '48e69555d778f9b9a3a1d553b9c3b8f7dd6a3394ac82df1433b60a69c055d47p',
    picture: 'petro huge.jpg',
    dob: '1856-12-20'
  },
  '48e69555d778f9b9a3a1d553b9c3b8f7dd6a3394ac82df1433b60a69c055d55j': {
    name: 'Mark Henry',
    userID: '48e69555d778f9b9a3a1d553b9c3b8f7dd6a3394ac82df1433b60a69c055d55j',
    picture: 'mark-henry.jpg',
    dob: '2005-12-29'
  }
}
```

I need to get picture from an api which is asynchronous, so used async await inside the reduce method. The problem here is it is always showing as Promise pending. If this was an array of object, then i can return Promise.all, but since this is object containing object how can i proceed with this inside reduce method? I need the exact same expected output.

Can somebody help me with this? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `acc` will be a promise after the first iteration (since `async` functions return a promise).

Comment: Why is the name of the variable `filteredArr` when its content is an object? The name suggests that it stores the result of a `Array.prototype.filter()` call.

Comment: @FelixKling yes can you let me know how can we do this?

Comment: You could use Promise.all() to make all the necessary API calls first, then use `.reduce` after and pass a sync function.

Comment: @ChrisG It would be great if you can provide a snippet for the same.

Comment: Just don't use `reduce` here :) It makes things unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @Andreas Yes it's a typo, thanks for that. I will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `reduce` while iterating over items asynchronously, you'd have to have the accumulator which gets passed from callback to callback to be a Promise. While this is possible, it'll make things pretty difficult to read, and introduces some unnecessary syntax noise.

Use a plain `for` loop instead:

```
const filteredArr = {};
for (const item of LargeArr.Items) {
  const { attributes: { dob, name, picture} = { dob: null, name: null, picture: null } } = item;
  const pic = picture ? await getPic(picture) : null;
  filteredArr[userID] = { name, uesrID, pic, dob };
}
```

If you really wanted to take the `reduce` route:

```
LargeArr.Items.reduce(
  (acc, { attributes: { dob, name, picture} = { dob: null, name: null, picture: null }, userID }) => {
    return acc.then(async (acc) => {
      let pic = null;
      if (picture) { pic = await getPic(picture); } // async here
      acc[userID] = { name, userID, pic, dob };
      return acc;
    });
  }, Promise.resolve({})
)
  .then((filteredArr) => {
    // do stuff with filteredArr
  });
```

Unless the `getPic` calls need to be made in serial, you could consider using `Promise.all` instead, to iterate through the whole array at once, rather than waiting on the resolution of the prior Promise before going onto the next.

If your API can handle `Promise.all`:

```
const filteredArr = {};
await Promise.all(LargeArr.Items.map(async (item) => {
  const { attributes: { dob, name, picture} = { dob: null, name: null, picture: null } } = item;
  const pic = picture ? await getPic(picture) : null;
  filteredArr[userID] = { name, uesrID, pic, dob };
}));
```

Comment: The second example won't work since `acc` isn't a promise in the first iteration. But if you do `acc = await acc;` instead of `return acc.then(...)` (and make the outer function `async`) then it should work.

Comment: @certainperformance inside for of const attributes destructuring, i think one brace is missing right?

Comment: @Vishnu Yeah, fixed it. Nested destructuring makes things hard to read and write, might want to avoid it when possible

Comment: @CertainPerformance I didnt get your point on getPic calls made serial and using Promise.all. It would be great if you can explain a bit. Thanks.

Comment: @Vishnu Say `getPic` takes 1 second. Then, if there are 5 pictures in the array, your current method and `for..of` will take 5 seconds total. But if you use `Promise.all`, you can send all requests out at once, so it'll only take 1 second total. But if `getPic` needs to run in serial (one after the other), then stick with the `for` loop instead of `Promise.all`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance ok. will there be any issue if we use Promise.all here?

Comment: @Vishnu It depends on `getPic`. If `getPic` operates in serial, or can't handle multiple calls at once (eg, if it's throttled), use the `for` method. Otherwise, if it doesn't have any parallel problems, use `Promise.all`

Comment: @CertainPerformance In my case i am creating a pre-signed url from s3 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html